# Solving Integral Equation by Converting to Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations, integro-differential-equations

Consider the problem

$$\phi(x) = x - \int_0^x(x-s)\phi(s)\,ds$$

How can we solve this by converting to a differential equation?

Answer (score 4):

We have that
$$\phi(x)=x-x\int_0^x \phi(s) \mathrm{d} s + \int_0^x s \phi(s)\mathrm{d}s$$
From this, we can see that $\phi(0)=0$.
We can differentiate both sides and use the product rule and the FTC1 to get:
$$\phi'(x)=1-\int_0^x \phi(s) \mathrm{d}s -x \phi(x)+x\phi(x)$$
$$\phi'(x)=1-\int_0^x \phi(s) \mathrm{d} s$$
From this, we can see that $\phi'(0)=1$. We can differentiate it again:
$$\phi''(x)=-\phi(x)$$
Which is an alternative definition of the $\sin$ function.

Comment: In fact, the only valid solution for $\phi(x)$ is $\sin{(x)}$ because of the original equation.

Comment: @PeterForemann Yes. I calculated $\phi(0)$ and $\phi'(0)$ from the integral equation to avoid the lengthy substitution and integration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you mind if I ask how you got $\phi ''(x) = -\phi (x)$ by differentiating $\phi ' (x)$? I don't understand the steps taken.

Comment: @LightningStrike Do you see how did I get $\phi'(x)=1-\int_0^x \phi(s) \mathrm{d}s$?

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating both sides  using [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) :

$${\phi }'(x)=1-\int_{0}^{x}{\phi (s)ds}$$

Differentiate again:

$${\phi }''(x)=-\phi (x)$$

Comment: Your answer is great, but Leibniz's rule is an overkill here, because it requires partial derivatives and the proof is based on measure theory.

Comment: may be you are right...but this is a common technique in an introductory course of integral equations.

Comment: I didn't take any course in integral equations, but we used Leibniz's rule during a physics course (without a proof), and it's a really useful tool to have. And we don't really know which is the appropriate solution to the questioner.